# Ionic v3, where to find the doc about directives

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, directive

I often read people mentioning about directive in Ionic, example :

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
```

or

```
<ion-header no-border>
```

i have gone through ionic documentation (current, not v1), and i can't find a place where the directive as `color` and `no-border` are covered.

Where can i find a comprehensive listing of those directive, and a way to know which component they can apply to ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start,have to know some basics in ionic 3. In ionic, Ionic team have introduced lots of predefined directive for better rendering.

**color and no-border** are predefined directive in ionic 3 and I don't think you can get these comprehensive list of directive details.

If you know the basics of ionic 1, you can get used to it easily.Otherwise it will take some time to learn.

Remember one thing, Ionic documentation doesn't have the full directive details and how to use it.

Best thing is, You can find the answer on various sites,blogs,forum,when it is needed...

This is the link for creating ionic directive in ionic 2&3.
   https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-directive-in-ionic-2-parallax-header/

Comment: thanks, am i the only one disapointed that the directives ionic introduced are not covered in an official place ? And are you saying that ionic v1 documentation covers them ?

Comment: ionic v1 documentation doesn't cover all of them, but you will get some idea and how directives are worked.If you know some basics of ionic 1, it will helpful little bit

Comment: i'm gonna select your answer, but i'm really surprised that a framework has some features that are not documented. It's like a library with functions which are not documented... how are we supposed to use them if they are not listed.... ?